# Marca-d'água com WideImage Com png

Tags: php

Estou tentando adicionar uma marca d'agua via php com a biblioteca [Wideimage](http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/).

```
    include 'WideImage/WideImage.php';
    $img = WideImage::load($targetFile);
    $watermark = WideImage::load('../images/logowater.png');
    $img = $img->merge($watermark, 'right-20','bottom-20', 60);

    $img->saveToFile($targetFile);
```

`$targetFile é o nome do arquivo base`

Está funcionando normalmente, porem se a imagem for um .png, a  marca é aplicada e o espaço da imagem aplicada fica toda em branco, eu precisaria que fosse aplicado o png.
Existe algum macete que passou despercebido?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolvido,

Apliquei a transparência direto na imagem, aumentando a opacidade.

Modifiquei no `merge`o quantidade de transparência de 60 para 100

`$img = $img->merge($watermark, 'right-20','bottom-20', 100);`